# Custom Handler Doesn't Like Spaces On Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom handler implementing IHttpHandler. The custom handler allows us to produce a dynamic URL for people to download files.

The code looks like this,

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + attachment.FileName);
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", attachment.Fileblob.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.ContentType = GetMimeType(attachment.FileName);
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(attachment.Fileblob, 0, attachment.Fileblob.Length);
}
```

The problem is with attachment.Filename. If the filename happens to have a space like this,

filename - 1.bmp

Then on internet explorer it works fine, but on firefox the file download dialog truncates it to be this,

filename

No extension or anything. I also tried this,

attachment.FileName.Replace(" ", "%20")

Which works in IE again, but in firefox it results in the filename being set to this in the download dialog,

filename%20-%201.bmp

I also tried this,

HttpUtility.UrlEncode(attachment.FileName)

In both firefox and IE that results in this,

filename+-+1.bmp

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing actual space characters with `%20` instead. Should still work across all browsers.

**Edit**

Ok, so that doesn't appear to have helped. Plan B, then.

Let's try tweaking our `Content-Disposition` HTTP header so that the attachment filename is wrapped in double quotes, per [RFC 2231](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2231.txt).

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", attachment.FileName));
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", attachment.Fileblob.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.ContentType = GetMimeType(attachment.FileName);
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(attachment.Fileblob, 0, attachment.Fileblob.Length);
}
```

Comment: Works well mostly. In IE it turns files with a hash in them like 'filename#.docx' to 'filename_.docx'. Not high priority though.